# two wires (getRecord, getObjectInfo) in a single in Lightning Web Components (LWC). Need to chain one after the other

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm trying to fetch the record values and show the label of the fields that have null values on the record detail page.

The code snippet is as below:

```
objectInfo = {};

@wire(getObjectInfo, {objectApiName: Lead_OBJECT })
LeadInfo({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.objectInfo = data;
    }
}

@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: "$recordId",
    fields: ['Company']
})
lead({error, data}) {
    if (data) {
        if (!data.fields['Company'].value) {
            console.log(this.objectInfo.fields['Company'].label);//getting an error here
        }
    }
}
```

Error is objectInfo is undefined certain times and doesnt understand objectInfo.fields. This doesn't happen every time I load the page, only sometimes this error occurs on refresh. I understand this is because both run asynchronously. what is the way to make this work?

Comment: Can u check by writing it in Connected callback one after another?

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar to get picklist values for a certain record type, and this works for me - I get the object info, assign the record type I need to the accountRTID variable, which in change triggers the picklist value lookup

```
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import STATEOFREP_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.kw__StateOfCoverage__c';

export default class myClass extends LightningElement {
objectInfo;
accountRTID;

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
wireObject(result) {
    if (result.data) {
        this.objectInfo = result.data;
        const rtis = this.objectInfo.recordTypeInfos;
        this.accountRTID = Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'KW - Member');
    } else if (result.error) {
        this.error = result.error;
    }
}

@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$accountRTID', fieldApiName: STATEOFREP_FIELD })
stateOptions;
```

I can then reference the stateOptions value in my component

Answer (score 1):

Can you somehow based on when you require data, do dynamic binding in getRecord ?
try making objectInfo reactive (@track), change in dynamic '$objectInfo' will trigger the Javascript functions which are dependent on it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

I ended up loading the Case record manually (not using wire) and I called it from within the "handleLoad" event handler...

js:

```
handleLoad() {
    this.initializeCase();
}//handleLoad
```

html:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form id="caseEditForm" record-id={recordId}
                record-type-id={infoPacket.theCase.RecordTypeId} object-api-name="Case" onerror={handleError}
                onload={handleLoad} onsubmit={handleSubmit} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
```

The "initializeCase" function did all my Case loading and initializing and then updated "tracked" variables that all cascade to updates on the LWC.  It does appear to load a little "slow" (user can see the fields update after the initial display of the window)... but in my situation the delay is negligible and works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the @wire from getRecord method and call this method in a implicit way, I assume it is being called based on certain events from UI.

Comment: Thanks Santanu, But NO it needs this to happen on load of the record detail page and not on any other ui event.

Comment: Rather than wire you can use connectedcallback method and do method chaining.